# improving speed performance on a data call

Tags: android, performance

I am making an API call to a web service from the android application the problem is that it returns around 22000 records, I am loading this into an array after i convert each record into an object then assign that Array to a ListView. What is the fastest/best way to fetch this data from the web service? (buffer) ? and what are the best practices for this type of issues.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by uploading it.  This occurs after the Array/Listview processing?

Comment: I meant what is the fastest/best way to fetch the data from the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a library to handle your data call...

Please try using [Android Query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/); specifically, see the section entitled [Asynchronous Network](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI).

This [AQuery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) library (**AndroidQuery**) is lightweight, and requires only 1 jar SMALL jar file. It can be used with Maven or Gradle Android projects as well. It allows you to EASILY fetch XML or JSON data from a remote server in either asynchronous or synchronous fashion. I have used it many times with a JSON back-end, and it is a real timesaver.

This library also allows you to specify a *ProgressBar* that will automatically appear and disappear during the network download process.

Here is an example of an HTTP call to a JSON back-end, asynchronously:

```
public void asyncJson(){

    //perform a Google search in just a few lines of code

    String url = "http://www.google.com/uds/GnewsSearch?q=Obama&v=1.0";
    aq.ajax(url, JSONObject.class, this, "jsonCallback");

}

public void jsonCallback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {

    if(json != null) {
            //successful ajax call
    } else {
            //ajax error
    }

}
```

AQuery can also simplify other aspects of Android programming (such as eliminating the findViewById() calls for many scenarios).

Comment: nice will take a look at it.

Comment: What format is the data from your service? (xml, json, etc...)

Comment: it is json, i got the json, but now it takes so long to convert to object one by one.

Comment: Do you control the JSON from the server? Perhaps the JSON needs to be more precise. OR.. do you need to fetch all 22,000 records at once? Can this be paged? You may want to use a pager, depending on what you're doing with it. 22,000 records is a long of memory for a phone too.. I could recommend chopping it up some how.

Comment: Yes,i would like to be able to say... bind 100 at a time.. with a spinner while i keep loading more.. - I dont understand why the -1, its a valid question :(.

Comment: Why do you need 22,000 items in memory at the same time? Might be too much, depending on the device and the logic of your app. If you fetch 100 at a time, then wait for the user to click or swipe for the next set of records..